# TFS Build fails but 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)

Tags: .net, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I created a CI build for one of our solutions that builds fine on our local machines, but fails all the time on TFS.

As mentioned:

- Builds fine on local machine - even after clean/rebuild. All other
  dev machines as well.
- I'm using the default build template. Actually this was a clone from another build that works just fine.
- Logging (even on verbosity 'diagnostic' shows no occurrences of 'error' or 'failed' other than the message about the zipping the logs.

TFS Version is 2013. The build machine was updated to VS2012v4. I'm not sure about TFS Build service version, but I'm having it updated to latest version next week. (Could that be it?)

Any ideas?

Googling resulted in:

- Upgrading VS on build server
- Upgrading TFS build service on build
  server (will be done monday by ops)

(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c0952875-10e8-4ae6-82a4-49af9db4a806/code-coverage-results-pending?forum=tfsbuild)

[image: TFS build error message]

Full error message here:

```
Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
 No zip file of logs was created because the archive operation failed: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Load(JsonReader reader)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(String json)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.ArchiveLogsInvoker.<ArchiveLogs>d__5.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.ArchiveLogsInvoker.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.OperationInvokerPool.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Load(JsonReader reader)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(String json)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.ArchiveLogsInvoker.<ArchiveLogs>d__5.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Load(JsonReader reader)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(String json)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.ArchiveLogsInvoker.<ArchiveLogs>d__5.MoveNext()<---
<---
```

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio installed on build server? Do you have any unit test projects as part of solution, esp. MSTest and Fakes?

Comment: We're running VS2012 update 4 on the build server but we're running an older version of the build service. We're upgrading everything now in order to follow the advice given here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c0952875-10e8-4ae6-82a4-49af9db4a806/code-coverage-results-pending?forum=tfsbuild. We have some tests, but I'm not running them.

Answer (score 0):

You might have compatibility problems when using TFS 2013 and VS 2012. Microsoft have changed the way build executes. I had similar problem when everything worked well on local machine but failed when I tried to build project with TFS 2013.